# Method to Install dependencies for Application not destined for CPAN

Tags: perl

It looks like most Perl modules declare their dependencies on other modules in the Makefile.PL, then CPAN uses that to install those dependencies.

But now I'm making not a module, but an end-user application that will never end up on CPAN, and I'd like it to be easy to install that application's dependencies on any given machine. Is there a Perl standard way to do that?

Comment: Make it a module anyway (perhaps call it `App::...`). It can then be installed with whatever build system you use (e.g. [`Module::Build`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build)) or with tools like [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus). A build system will take care of dependencies, but will also make it easier to install, test, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a module anyway and put it in the [`App::…` namespace](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module;query=App%3A%3A). The code will live in the `lib/App/**.pm` library files, and the script will be only a thin wrapper; [perlfind](https://metacpan.org/source/MARCEL/App-perlfind-2.05/bin/perlzonji) is a good example. Use a CLI framework such as [MooseX::App](http://p3rl.org/MooseX::App) to help split functionality into modules, which makes the code easier to test and reuse.

As you already know, a module-based distribution declares its dependencies either directly with a [metafile](http://p3rl.org/CPAN::Meta::Spec) or indirectly with a build system, and is then packaged by you with any build system (e.g. [Module::Build](http://p3rl.org/Module::Build)) or installed by a user with any installation tool (e.g. [cpanm](http://p3rl.org/cpanm)).

Comment: Answer based on and expanded from [an earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26052341#comment-40813549), kindly upvote [Biffen](http://stackoverflow.com/u/418066).

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up question: Module::Build appears to use CPAN shell to install dependencies. But some won't install it appears because not all tests pass. If I open the shell myself, I could force install, but is there a way to configure Module::Build to force or notest install dependencies?